# Executing function on focus in Chrome and Safari

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, safari, focus, blur

I am trying to build a fullsized background-slider that stops playing when the tab/window is inactive and continues when it's focused.

The problem is that Chrome and Safari both don't do anything on loading/refreshing the page - you have to click out- and then inside the window for them to start the animation.

Is there any way to avoid this?

This is my code so far:

```
$(window).load( function(){ 
    var autopager;

    function startAutopager() {
        autopager = window.setInterval("slideSwitch()", 5000);
    }

    function stopAutopager() {
        window.clearInterval(autopager);
    }

    window.addEventListener('focus', startAutopager);   
    window.addEventListener('blur', stopAutopager);

    slideSwitch();
    $("#sliderContent img").fullBg();
});
```

This starts the animation for both browsers but when I click outside the window again it won't stop:

```
if(true == $.browser.safari || true == $.browser.chrome) {
    startAutopager();
}
```

Hope someone can help.

Cheers!

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using jQuery's methods for binding events? Also, I noticed that you're using setInterval which is strongly discouraged in the documentation: [link](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)  See "Additional Notes"

Comment: Thanks for answering! I didn't know about binding events, but I'll have a look at that.
SetInterval maybe discouraged but in my case it's no problem or is it?

Comment: It would seem to me that, knowing JS, focus/blur will not always be called properly. It's _possible_ that focus could get called twice in a row... causing your slideSwitch() function to fire twice: "queuing" more animations than you want it to. Perfect practice might be to use:

`if (autopager) window.clearInterval(autopager);`
`autopager = window.setInterval("slideSwitch()", 5000);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and let me know in a comment how it goes. :)

```
$(function(){
  $("#sliderContent img").fullBg();

  var autopager;
  function startAutopager() {
    if (autopager) window.clearInterval(autopager);
    autopager = window.setInterval("slideSwitch()", 5000);
  }
  function stopAutopager() {
    window.clearInterval(autopager);
  }
  window.focus(startAutopager);   
  window.blur(stopAutopager);
  startAutopager()
});
```

Comment: First of all thank you!
I replaced
   window.focus(startAutopager);   
   window.blur(stopAutopager);
by
    window.addEventListener('focus', startAutopager);    
    window.addEventListener('blur', stopAutopager);
and now it seems to work!